# Como mudar o idioma do documento em rmarkdown usando latex?

Tags: r, latex, rmarkdown

Estou escrevendo um documento na Rmarkdown e usando o Latex para figuras e tabelas. Eu preciso dos títulos das figuras e tabelas em português, então eu tentei o seguinte:

Arquivo de rmarkdown:

```
     ---
     Output:
       pdf_document:
           includes:
                 in_header: mystyles.sty
       html_document: rmarkdown :: github_document
       word_document: default
     ---
```

arquivo mystyles.sty:

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
```

No entanto, quando crio o documento usando `rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd ")`, aparece o erro:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `portuguese'. Either you misspelled it (babel) or the language definition file portuguese.ldf was not found.
```

Como estou no Ubuntu, rodei:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese
```

que retorna que eu já tenho este pacote instalado:

```
texlive-lang-portuguese is already the newest version (2015.20160223-1).
```

Eu também tentei rodar o `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european` que retorna o mesmo

O que eu estou fazendo errado aqui? Porque o compilador de latex não está reconhecendo o comando?

Comment: Você encontra o documento "portuguese.ldf"? Porque o erro diz que não é possível encontrá-lo...

Comment: Obrigado. Isso resolveu meu problema. No terminal, digitei `find . -type f -name "*.ldf"` que retornou umas lista de arquivos `ldf`  e, entre eles, o bendito `portuges.ldf`. Ou seja, não é nem `portuguese` e nem `portugues` é `portugese`. De onde eles tiraram essa ortografia que é um mistério